# Trying to pull Heroku database onto my localhost

Tags: heroku, psql

I recently made a mistake by rolling back my database too far on my localhost and removed all the data from within the databases I've had. I did migrate the databases so they would return but they still were cleaned out.

Asking around what to do next, I was told that I should backup the database on Heroku (which has all the current information) and pull it onto my localhost. If this is the correct action to take, then I am still facing a problem. When I type:
`heroku pg:pull DATABASE_URL mylocaldb --app (my_app_name)` it returns an error of:

```
sh: createdb: command not found
!    
! Unable to create new local database. Ensure your local Postgres is
working and try again.
```

I do not have the best understanding of databases as I am newer; however, I have downloaded sql on my local machine. All of the commands I input are in the regular console and not the psql terminal.

If anyone has any knowledge or can help me, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you so much!

Joe

Edit: If you do have another method/solution, please let me know. I cannot update my application until I have this done so I do not lose my information.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using backup/restore:

```
heroku pg:backups --app MYAPPNAME capture
curl -o latest.dump `heroku pg:backups --app MYAPPNAME public-url`
```

as (almost) documented at 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

Note the strange placement of `--app MYAPPNAME`. It needs to go immediately after the heroku sub-command and before any other arguments.

Comment: pg_restore does not work as I receive `-bash: pg_restore: command not found` - I think this was what made me initially try the pg:pull method. the pg:backup and curl work fine but not the final step.

Comment: Sounds like an error in your $PATH / broken Posgres install. My pg_restore is sitting in /usr/bin/pg_restore. You could also try the pgAdmin app. The Restore... option is in the context menu for the database.

Comment: I appreciate it but it was actually a much bigger issue. Heroku uses Postgres and I was using Sqlite3 locally. I ended up deleting sqlite3 completely and using PG on my project. I wrote a little blog about it here (http://www.joedayvie.com/articles/11), in case anyone wishes to see.